# How can access the second document in a Firebase Firestore collection in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named "wallpapers" on my firebase firestore, where each document in my collection has three entries among which one is named 'url'. How can I access the 'url' section of the second document in flutter? Here's what I am trying to do:

```
String header_url;
  Firestore.instance.collection('wallpapers').getDocuments().then((document) {
    header_url = document.documents.elementAt(1).data['url'];
  });
  NetworkImage header = NetworkImage(header_url);
```

And here's what I get in my logs:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on QMobile Z10 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
E/flutter (19630): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 486 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true.
E/flutter (19630): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:39)
E/flutter (19630): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
E/flutter (19630): #2      new NetworkImage (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:486:14)
E/flutter (19630): #3      main (package:querencia/main.dart:13:25)
E/flutter (19630): #4      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:199:25)
E/flutter (19630): #5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
E/flutter (19630): #6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
E/flutter (19630): #7      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
E/flutter (19630): #8      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1500:12)
E/flutter (19630): #9      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:190:5)
E/flutter (19630): #10     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:300:19)
E/flutter (19630): #11     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:171:12)
E/flutter (19630): 
Syncing files to device QMobile Z10...
D/SQLiteDatabase(19630): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(19630): endTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(19630): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(19630): endTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(19630): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(19630): endTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(19630): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(19630): endTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(19630): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(19630): endTransaction()
V/InputMethodManager(19630): START INPUT: io.flutter.view.FlutterView{85d34b5 VFE..... .F...... 0,0-1080,1776} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@3723d594 controlFlags=#100
D/ActivityThread(19630): ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{136c51 token=android.os.BinderProxy@aebfcb6 {com.technoscans.querencia/com.technoscans.querencia.MainActivity}}
D/ActivityThread(19630): ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@aebfcb6
V/ActivityThread(19630): Finishing stop of ActivityRecord{136c51 token=android.os.BinderProxy@aebfcb6 {com.technoscans.querencia/com.technoscans.querencia.MainActivity}}: show=true win=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow@3d76d983
D/ActivityThread(19630): ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_SHOW handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@aebfcb6
D/SQLiteDatabase(19630): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(19630): endTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(19630): beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase(19630): endTransaction()
V/InputMethodManager(19630): START INPUT: io.flutter.view.FlutterView{85d34b5 VFE..... .F...... 0,0-1080,1776} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@2c8c432c controlFlags=#100
V/InputMethodManager(19630): START INPUT: io.flutter.view.FlutterView{85d34b5 VFE..... .F...... 0,0-1080,1776} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@143831f5 controlFlags=#100
I/System.out(19630): [CDS]close[56739]
I/System.out(19630): [CDS][DNS] getAllByNameImpl netId = 0
D/libc-netbsd(19630): [getaddrinfo]: hostname=firestore.googleapis.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
D/libc-netbsd(19630): [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
D/libc-netbsd(19630): [getaddrinfo]: hostname=firestore.googleapis.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
D/libc-netbsd(19630): [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
D/libc-netbsd(19630): getaddrinfo: firestore.googleapis.com get result from proxy >>
I/System.out(19630): propertyValue:true
```

Comment: My question is, I am trying to access the 'url' key value pair in the second document of firestore collection. While my code isn't giving me a url in my header_url variable. Which is why NetworkImage is throwing an exception. So, my question is why isn't it returning me a url to be stuffed inside the NetworkImage() command.

Comment: it could be helpful to share your "wallpapers" structure. Just to make sure you're accessing to each field correctly. Also, read this  [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51) carefully

Comment: `header_url = document.documents.elementAt(2).data['url'];`?

Comment: Thanks... Worked for me :)